# Cookies in async function Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, json

my question is : can you save a cookie inside an async function ?

Like making a cookie of this fetch, an use it later inside the same function while the fetch still updating the value each time the function is called ?

```js
async function organise(){
       let result = await fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/maxitem.json').then((response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Don't use the old-style `.then()` inside `async` functions.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but why not store it as a variable outside the function and then update the variable each time the function is called?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "cookie". A cookie is not a JS variable. And cookies should (generally) not be used for storing script data.

Comment: @kdsprogrammer we can't store inside a variable outside an asynchronous function unfortunately :/

Comment: @Dai Hum thanks for the tips I will learn the new style so :)     hum I am talking of something like a pointer my bad ^^"

Comment: @antwaneuh JavaScript doesn't have pointers, and pointers have _even less_ to do with cookies. Now **I really want to know** what you think "cookies" and "pointers" means...

Comment: @antwaneuh why can't you store a variable outside an async function? I don't think we fully understand the context of what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help I understood my problem and it wasn't this my really bad thanks for your help ^^"